# Android USB I/O

Tags: android, usb

OK, so i *have* seen all the stuff about how acting as a USB host is impossible on vanilla android, but is there anything in the Android API that would allow an app to override the default USB behavior in order to manually control the USB i/o responses, in order to support some other protocol?  I have not seen anything that would facilitate this, but is it possible without hacking the kernel?

This seems like the sort of thing which *should* be relatively easy, but i haven't found anything.  Forgive me if i've been googling incorrectly.

Comment: you're seeing the solution, but not the problem. What problems are you trying to solve that makes you think you need USB host mode?

Comment: I don't think i need USB host mode.  I was just clarifying that i already knew that it was impossible without hacks, to try and ward off the inevitable "didn't you use google?" crowd.  I just want a way to be able to manually manage USB traffic, instead of having Android handle it automatically (ie, when you plug the droid into a computer, and android goes into USB mode- i want to be able to interrupt this process and set up my own handler for data traffic).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the stock kernel does not include the correct drivers for this. You need to be able to root your device and you need one of the devices capable of acting as a USB host.

See this page, http://sven.killig.de/android/N1/2.2/usb_host/

The linked page had source for the kernel and drivers you'll need ... GOOD LUCK, you'll need it

Answer (score 0):

Last year I worked on an application that had a PC component and a smartphone component, and the two were communicating over a USB connection (using ADB port forwarding and regular sockets). So, if you want to do something like that, I'll show you how I did it, maybe it's helpful.

Comment: That's a clever solution... though raw access to the data stream would be ideal. But I certainly had not thought of that.

Comment: I briefly explained what I did at the following link. There's also some sample code following the link at the bottom of the post. Hope it helps! http://www.anothem.net/archives/2010/02/15/communicating-over-the-usb-cable/

Answer (score 0):

> USB On-The-Go (USB OTG or just OTG) is a specification first used in
>   late 2001 that allows USB devices, such as tablets or smartphones, to
>   act as a host

@Wikipedia, If anybody is still looking for it

In order to manage usb traffic your device needs to become a host according to USB specification.