# Access Pc through Android Device Sensor

Tags: android

I want to make an app in android which acts as a bluetooth keyboard/mouse to Pc. What is the Api available in android for this purpose and what are the ways of implementing it.

Comment: This would be easier if you get rid of the USB approach and instead send the events over Wi-Fi to a server app on your PC.

Comment: Another possibility is to use bluetooth.

Comment: Ya i am planning to use Wifi for that..I also came to know that using Sensor can get the movements of the mobile.thnks 4 ur reply

Comment: I think it is the shortest way, a small JavaSE socket server on a machine on your WLAN, and an android app opening a socket to that machine. Read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html . The client code should run on Android too (inside an activity) since it uses only java.net and java.io classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to capture user touch events. Show a dumb view and then override [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) in your activity.

Then, you have to send the events via usb. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html). I'm not sure if the PC is the host or the accesory in your case, but a plain PC won't use the Android Accesory Protocol. You'll probably have to write a "driver" to your app.

UPDATE:
Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955486/813951) for an awesome approach using regular sockets and adb port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html